# wifi debugging Android 11 device paired but not detected by Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I have successfully paired my device Samsung Galaxy tab A7 lite

the tab is paired using `adb pair ip address and then pairing code`

it shows successfully paired in command line (cmd) however the device is not detected by android studio artic fox

the same device works perfectly using USb debugging

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also need to run this command after pairing.

`adb connect ip_address:port_number`